# Make Classwork tab the default screen when students open google classroom, not the stream page

Tags: google-classroom

Elementary kids can't handle the stream, how can we make the classwork tab the default page when they log in to their classroom.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to directly request the feature via the Classroom feedback link (the question mark ?, "Report issue or request feature") on your Classroom homepage... then get all your colleagues to do the same! ;-)